# app crashes when create alertDialog with a null context

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I'm a new android developer, suffering from a problem recently.

The background is that i need to show an `AlertDialog` when a back-end asyncTask finished. However the activity may be **GC'd** after a long time asyncTask, so that the context tobe input param of AlertDialog is null.Is there any workaround to solve this problem.

I use this function to show dialog:

```
public static Dialog showDialog(
            Context ctx, int themeId, String title, String message,
            int okStrId, android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener,
            int cancelStrId, android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener cancelListener) {
        if (ctx != null) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder;
            if (themeId > 0)
                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(ctx, themeId));
            else
                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
            if (title != null)
                builder.setTitle(title);
            builder.setMessage(message);
            builder.setPositiveButton(ctx.getString((okStrId < 0) ? R.string.ok : okStrId),
                    (okListener != null) ? okListener : sDefaultDialogListener);
            if (cancelListener != null)
                builder.setNegativeButton(ctx.getString((cancelStrId < 0) ? R.string.cancel : cancelStrId), cancelListener);
            else {
                builder.setCancelable(false);
            }
            AlertDialog ad = builder.create();
            ad.show();
            return ad;
        }else {
            Context context = SuccessFactorsApp.getAppContext();
            DialogActivity.launchActivity(ctx,themeId,title,message,okStrId,okListener,cancelStrId,cancelListener);
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        }
    }
```

I tried to use an Activity to simulate the dialog but not sure how to deal with the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`.

Comment: Please post your LogCat!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code:

```
if(!((Activity) context).isFinishing())
{
    //show dialog
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.The problem is that i need to show dialog even if the activity is garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

While running asyntask and doing background activity gets killed and Garbage collected..Hence on completion of task you cannot show a dialog without activity.You can try either

1.By adding below permission showing your dialog .Add this permission to manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

And while showing dialog add this line of code before dialog.show()

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
```

2.On finsihing of the task launch the wanted activity and open application

3.Use Toast instead of dialog.